# How can I select certain HTML-Element in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to select certain HTML elements in a DIV. Something like this:

```
$("#foo table,tr,td,span,p" ).addClass( Myclass );
```

But it adds the class also outside of DIV "#foo".
I.e. only the elements in div "#foo" are the class "Myclass" to add.
Thanks.

Comment: `$("#foo table, #foo tr, #foo td, #foo span, #foo p").addClass("Myclass");`

Comment: Because your selectors after the comma are generic, you need to specify #foo before each elem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem:** Comma `,` separates autonomous selectors. You have to select `#foo` first, then select your inner elements `table, tr, td, span, p`.

You can use *context* attribute:

```
$("table, tr, td, span, p", "#foo").addClass("Myclass");
```

or you can chain your selectors:

```
$("#foo").find("table, tr, td, span, p").addClass("Myclass");
```

Comment: @user3417601 I'm glad that your problem is solved :) Please accept the answer which has helped you the most.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it this way, each element has to have the parent id, i.e. `#foo`, before it and you need to wrap your class-name, i.e. `myClass`, with `""`.

```
$("#foo table, #foo tr, #foo td, #foo span, #foo p").addClass("Myclass");
```

Answer (score 2):

When you add a comma, you are separating you selectors. Try

```
$("#foo table, #foo tr, #foo td, #foo span, #foo p" ).addClass( Myclass );
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you intending to select the tables, tr, td, spans, and p within div with ID foo? That selector would be more like

`$("#foo table,#foo tr, #foo td, #foo span, #foo p")`

Your current selector is saying "all tables inside div with ID "foo" and then also all tr, td, spans, and p on the whole document

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways of doing it:

Method 1:

```
$("#foo").find("table, tr, td, span, p").addClass("Myclass");
```

Method 2:

```
$("#foo table , #foo tr, #foo td, #foo span, #foo p").addClass("Myclass");
```